# How to desgin a fair raffle

Tags: statistics

I need to organize a raffle and it has to be fair.

Some people have a peice of land that lets say has 22 owners, and in that land they are planning to build 39 apartments (maybe 47 but that's not the point), so they have a contractor that will build it, and in order to decide which owner gets which apartment they want to have a raffle.

They wanted to number all the apartments from 1 to 39 and draw from a hat.

By the way they only get 22 or 24 apartments, the rest go to the contractor as his payment.

Problem is it's not fair, because the first to draw had a 1/39 chance the second has a 1/38 etc.

I taught about using a 2 phase raffle with random number pages.

Phase 1, we select the order in which people raffle using the random numbers, this phase is important in my opinion since not every apartment is the same there are 2 penthouses 2 garden apartments and other factors, so i order to keep everythibg fair, we also raffle the order of the raffle.

One important point about special apartments (penthouses and garden apartments) is that it may be agreed uopn in advance, that the contractor or an owner will get them WITHOUT a raffle, but that is ok since it was agreed upon.

After that is done using a w digit method we raffle for the apartments.

Is that fair enoguh? Is there a way to make a fully 100% fair raffle?

Thabks in advance

Comment: Pr(winning on second draw) = Pr(drawing the desired ticket) $\times$ Pr(**not** winning on first draw) = $\frac1{38} \times \frac{38}{39} = \frac 1{39}$, the same as winning on the first draw. The third draw takes into account not winning on either of the first two, and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure whybyou reffer to it as winning, every draw "wins" I just want the chance to draw each apartment to be the same regardless of when it was drawn

Comment: Every draw "wins", but lets look at the 1st person he has a 1/39 chance to win any apartment including the penthouses and the garden apartments, to.be more spesific he has a 2/39 to win a penthouse a 2/39 to win a garden apartment and a 35/39 to win regular apartment, i guess we agree to this point. Now comes the 2nd person, he will have 2/38, 2/38 and 34/38 since there are now only 38 nktes in the hat right? Isn't his chance to draw a penthouse or graden apartment increase? He has a 2/38 on each while the first drawer had only 2/39 on each

Answer (score 2):

Your statement that the first has $\frac 1{39}$ chance to win and the second has $\frac 1{38}$ is not correct.  The second has $\frac 1{39}$ chance and the raffle is fair.  You are imagining that the first does not win, which improves the odds for the second one, but some of the time the first will win.  If you do the detailed calcultion you will find the second one has $\frac 1{39}$ chance to win.  Alternately, let each of the first two draw their numbers without looking.  Then have the second person look at his number first.  How can the order they look change the odds?

Comment: Every draw "wins", but lets look at the 1st person he has a 1/39 chance to win any apartment including the penthouses and the garden apartments, to.be more spesific he has a 2/39 to win a penthouse a 2/39 to win a garden apartment and a 35/39 to win regular apartment, i guess we agree to this point. Now comes the 2nd person, he will have 2/38, 2/38 and 34/38 since there are now only 38 nktes in the hat right? Isn't his chance to draw a penthouse or graden apartment increase? He has a 2/38 on each while the first drawer had only 2/39 on each

Comment: No, you have not understood the point at all.  The fact that the first ticket is drawn does not change the odds unless you consider what it is.  If you know it is a losing ticket, the odds of the second person go up, but if it is a winning ticket the odds of the second person go down.  Those exactly balance out overall.  Try it on a smaller scale.  Assume there are three tickets and one wins.  You would claim the second person has $1/2$ chance of winning instead of $1/3$.  Your logic would claim the last person is certain to win.  The three draws possible are  LLW, LWL, WLL.  Each one wins 1/3

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment ...

Define $P$=Pr(penthouse on the first draw) = $\frac2{39}$,
$G$=Pr(garden on the first draw) = $\frac2{39}$,
$R$=Pr(regular on first draw) = $\frac{35}{39}$,

What happens in the second draw depends on the first:

Say $P_P$ is Pr(penthouse on the second draw given **penthouse** on the first) = $\frac{1}{38} \times P = \frac{2}{38\times39}$,

$P_G$ is Pr(penthouse on the second draw given **garden** on the first) = $\frac{2}{38} \times G = \frac{4}{38\times39}$,

$P_R$  is Pr(penthouse on the second draw given **regular** on the first) = $\frac{2}{38} \times R = \frac{70}{38\times39}$.

Putting these together,

Pr(penthouse on the second draw regardless of the first draw) = $P_P+P_G+P_R = \frac{76}{38\times39} = \frac2{39}$, the same probability as getting a penthouse on the first draw.