# Is it unordered selection without replacment?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Following my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044532/how-to-desgin-a-fair-raffle),

I tried to review my statics course which I took over a decade ago. (sorry forgot most of it, I rarely use it)

In any case the new conditions are as follows:

47 apartments are available.
there are 20 landowners and a contractor which split the apartments as follow.

23 - for landownder
24 - the contractor

Now as I understand this is an unordered selection without replacement.
Meaning it doesn't matter when you pick, you can be first to pick or last, your chance of getting any apartment is the same.

Am I right?

btw as you might have noticed k=n here since we pick 47 out of 47.

everyone insists they want to go first and the contractor insists it should alternating pick between landowners and him.

1. Am I correct that the order of selection doesn't matter? it is counter-intuitive to most people, as they think if they get to be first they have a better chance of getting a better selection
2. Is there a way to explain this to someone that doesn't understand the math?

to be honest I understand that the chance of the first one is $\frac{1}{47}$ and the second one is  $\frac{1}{46}$ etc meaning the total is $\frac{1}{47!}$

However, that is just the chance of getting that very specific order of selection. it doesn't explain why it doesn't matter who draws first and who draws last and how is it that everyone has the same chance to win any of the apartments (apartments are not of equal value).

Suggestion by one of the participants is that everyone put their hand in the hat together and take one ticket at the same time and take the hand out, he thinks it will be fair that way...., which intuitively it is, but I think the math doesn't support it

Thank you

Comment: You need to choose which $24$ apartments the contractor receives, then distribute the remaining $23$ apartments to the $20$ landowners.  The order of selection does not matter and the selections are made without replacement.

Comment: "The chance of getting **any** apartment is the same" is incorrect. Even if they are identical, I might have a favorite number or not want #13, so picking first gives me an advantage. However, the number wise distribution doesn't change with the order of selection

Comment: @N.F.Taussig we would like to give the contractor less advantage as possible, yet he insists that we pick 1st he 2nd we 3rd he 4th etc....

Comment: @trueblueanil Hi, Yes I understand that intuitively picking 1st gives an advantage. lets say I like apartments number 2, so if I pick 1st there is a 100% chance it is still in the hat, and I have a $\frac{1}{47}$ chance of getting it. however if I choose second and it's still in the hat than i have $\frac{1}{46}$ to get it which is a better chance assuming it was not picked before. meaning we go into the field of conditional probability. The cahcne of getting my fav apt if someone already picked it is ofc 0

Comment: So i calculated the following
Chance of first player to get apt #2 - $\frac{1}{47}$
Chance of second player to get #2 apt - $\frac{46}{47}$*$\frac{1}{46}$ + 0
explanation is P(First didn't win #2 apt) * P(Second won apt #2) + P(Chance of winning the 3@ apt if first already won which is 0) - that is also $\frac{1}{47}$ so chances are the same, or did I get something wrong?